# Traverse of linked entities with API client exposed by spring-data-rest

Tags: spring-data-rest, openapi-generator

With a generated client by openapi-generator (typescript-axios in my case), it is easy to request an entity that is exposed by spring-data-rest, let's say a Person entity with

```
const endpoint = PersonEntityControllerApiFactory(configuration);
endpoint.getItemResourcePersonGet('5000')
```

which gives me an object like

```
{
  "id" : "5000",
  "name" : "Mr. Anderson",
  "_links" : {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8888/api/persons/5000"
    },
    "addresses": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8888/api/persons/5000/addresses"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, is there an easy way to request the `addresses` collection of that entity with the generated API client (typescript-axios in my case)?

One compicated way comes to my mind to solve this. It's possible to provide a spring data rest projection for Person which inlines ids or complete Address entities into Person. But that would take some extra effort and would be against the HAL / HATEOAS idea.

Another way could be to perform a request on the provided addresses link manually (e.g. by calling axios). But that would question the use of a generated API client in general.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I'm currently trying to consume an spring-data-rest api with the open-api-generator for axios, but i have the feeling that the generated axios client makes no sense, because he has no functionality for traversal, i think i'm going back to write my own rest controllers

Comment: @wutzebaer we didn't find a proper way to use openapi/typescript-axios with spring-data-rest plus additional controller endpoints. We decided to rather give up on spring-data-rest as it also came with different issues for us. We now stick to openapi/typescript-axios and plain RESTController entpoints which works acceptable.

Comment: i think we'll go the same way, thank you